# How to launch several celery processes/queues and gracefully close them on container shut down?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, celery

```sh
# start 2 main processes in the background
# one with 1 worker and another with NUM_CPU workers
# each has separate queue 
celery multi start 2 -c:1 1 -Q:1 long -Q:2 default 

# somehow wait til container is shut down
while true; do sleep 5; done

# fetch termination signal
trap - SIGTERM SIGINT  # and maybe INT

# gracefully stop everything
celery multi stop
```

But here is the problem: docker can't send SIGTERM to our script unless some process inside it is running on behalf of docker command (has same PID or something, I don't know).

To run a process on behalf of the script we need to add `exec`, with the simple setup it looks like this:

```sh
# ...
exec celery -A app worker
```

But we can't add `exec` to anything in the original script because after that "anything" finishes working then everything will shut down.

Answer (score 0):

`docker stop` unfortunately first sends SIGTERM signal, and then after a certain period sends SIGKILL if SIGTERM was not handled on time, which is not what Celery expects for the graceful shutdown.

In order to do that (equivalent to Ctrl-C in console)  run `docker kill --signal=SIGINT your-container-name`.